# TimeZone Setting On PostgreSQL Databases

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu, timezone, postgresql-15, patroni

I have a **Patroni cluster** with two **Ubuntu 22 db server**. The timezone of my instances was set to **UTC**. I have needed to edit them to set the local timezone to **Europe/Istanbul**. I have made the timezone change on OS-level. When i checked the timezone setting with timedatectl command, i saw local time was correct.

And, I applied the setting one by one to all my databases on my server:

`ALTER DATABASE "db_name" SET TIMEZONE TO "Europe/Istanbul";`

Also applied the setting:

`ALTER SYSTEM SET TimeZone TO 'Europe/Istanbul';`

And i edited my patroni config file and entered timezone setting like:

`TimeZone: Europe/Istanbul`

After that, i restarted my patroni cluster. After restarting my cluster, i saw that some of databases had applied the changes but other ones had not. I checked those databases configuration. The configuration was same with the applied ones.

I still see old timezone setting which was ETC/UTC when I execute sql command below:

`show timezone`

I am a little bit confused about it. Strange situation. What might cause the situation? Do i miss something?

Comment: Some clients will automatically set the timezone upon connection, rather than accepting the servers default.  So you will have to describe what you used to do `show timezone` and how it was configured.  Also,  select * from pg_settings where name ilike 'Timezone'  will give more info than `show timezone` will.

Comment: I have used show timezone command to check the current TimeZone value in my postgresql settings. I also used this query: select * from pg_settings where name ilike 'Timezone' . There is something to do in my opinion but what should to do, i don't know. Those commands just shows the current value of the setting. The clients also don't set any timezone value.

Comment: If you just dismiss all the suggestions without evaluating them, then you will find that not solution exists because you won't look for one.   What did `select * from pg_settings where name ilike 'Timezone'` **show**?

Comment: @jjanes You are right . I have checked the settings from the query you sent. The result set is like this :

**name: TimeZone
setting: Etc/UTC
context: user
vartype: string
source: session**

I have saw that those databases's source type was session which did not apply timezone setting. 
The applied database's source type is database. I think this is the reason of difference.
I also connected those databases from psql client and queried them. I saw all databases in my Europe/Istanbul timezone.
But it is not same while connecting over PgAdmin,

Comment: The correct way to change a parameter value is `patrinictl edit-config`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe I have also done the way. I realize that situation changes from client to client for some databases. This is really interesting. First time to face for me.

Comment: Do you have any idea or any article about the situation? How can i force the clients to use database default timezone setting?